# how to remove underscore from values of textarea?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am getting values from textare as show in double qoutes

```
"Hi_i_am_working_on_javascript_comment_box"
```

how to remove underscore value from it...

Answer (score 21):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for example. Like that ([see proof here](http://ideone.com/HS3HB)):

```
$input = 'Hi_i_am_working_on_javascript_comment_box';

$output = str_replace('_', ' ', $input);
```

Answer (score 8):

use `str_replace` with php:

```
$string=str_replace("_"," ",$string);
```

Answer (score 3):

in sql

```
replace('Hi_i_am_working_on_javascript_comment_box', '_', ' ')
```